# Pyomo: Param and Var not constructed when placed in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

While modeling an optimisation problem using `pyomo` I noticed a weird behaviour when using a `list` of `Var` or `Param`: I always get the following error `ValueError: Evaluating the numeric value of parameter 'SimpleParam' before the Param has been constructed (there is currently no value to return).`

The following code (minise 4*x+1 such that x >= 0) runs exactly as expected:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def _obj(model):
    return model.c*model.x + 1

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.c = pyo.Param(initialize=lambda model: 4, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=_obj, sense=pyo.minimize)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(model)
```

but as I set `model.x` and `model.c` in `list`s, the program crashes when creating the objective function:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def _obj(model):
    return model.c[0]*model.x[0] + 1

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = [pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)]
model.c = [pyo.Param(initialize=lambda model: 4, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)]
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=_obj, sense=pyo.minimize)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(model)
```

What is causing this error? Is this a desired behaviour for a reason that I don't understand or is this a bug? Anyway, how can I use lists of `Param`s and `Var`s in a problem? I know that I can theoretically *flatten* all of my parameters and variables into a single `IndexedVar` or `IndexedParam` and handle the new indices myself, but that would be tedious since the range of the 3rd and 4th indices of my `x` and `c` depend on the 1st and 2nd index, therefore it would be a lot clearer in my code if I could use `list`s.

More precisely: I have a code looking like this (though I am still interested in knowning why the MWE above does not work):

```py
# I, J are lists of indices and N is a list of integer values
model.Vs = [pyo.RangeSet(N[i]) for i in range(len(N))]
model.xs = [[pyo.Var(model.Vs[i], model.Vs[j]) for j in J] for i in I]
model.cs = [[pyo.Param(model.Vs[i], model.Vs[j]) for j in J] for i in I]
def _obj(model):
    sum(model.xs[i][j][k,ell] * model.xs[i][j][k,ell] \\
        for i in I for j in J \\
        for k in model.Vs[i] for ell in model.Vs[j])

model.obj = Objective(rule=_obj, sense=pyo.minimize)
model.constraints = [
    [pyo.Constraint(model.Vs[i], model.Vs[j], rule=...) for j in J]
    for i in I
]
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(model)
```

Comment: Are you just winging this?  Did you read the dox?  :).  You are missing the key concept of making sets to use as indices for variables/parameters that are indexed.  There are many ways to do this.  Take a look at the simple examples in the dox or at some of my previous answers that have a `pyomo` tag on 'em.  Comment back if you are stuck.

Comment: As I said: I do use `RangeSet`s in my code, but the `RangeSet` for my 3rd index does depend on the first index, and the `RangeSet` for my 4th index does depend on the second index. Therefore I cannot make a `Var` with 4 `RangeSet`

Comment: You didn't say anything above about `RangeSet`.  It still isn't real clear what you want to do when you say "the range of the 3rd and 4th indices..."  Can you edit your code above to show more clearly an example of how you are trying to index even if it is pseudocode?  It sounds like you might need to double index some of your vars, which can be done.

Comment: I edited the post. Though beyond my own problem for my code, I would like to understand why the example I gave fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your minimal example

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def _obj(model):
    return model.c[0]*model.x[0] + 1

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.x = [pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)]
model.c = [pyo.Param(initialize=lambda model: 4, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)]
model.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=_obj, sense=pyo.minimize)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(model)
```

generates the following error:

```
ValueError: Evaluating the numeric value of parameter 'SimpleParam' before
        the Param has been constructed (there is currently no value to return).
```

The reason is because you are not directly attaching the `Var` and `Param` you are generating to the model.  A lot happens when you attach a Pyomo modeling component to a `Block` (`ConcreteModel` objects are instances of constructed Blocks):

- The component is assigned a *name* (that matches the Block attribute name)
- The component is inserted into the hierarchy (basically, pointers are set so that methods can walk up and down the model hierarchy)
- The component is categorized so that writers, solvers, and transformations can find it later
- (If the Block has already been constructed), the component is automatically constructed.

By placing the component in a list, you are effectively "hiding" its existence from Pyomo.  The first error you get has to do with this last bullet (the Param hasn't been constructed).  However, simply constructing the Param and Var as you build the list will be insufficient, as the other actions won't take place and you will just hit a different error later (the next error would be an obsure one when the LP writer comes across a Var in the Objective that it had not found when it first walked the model hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help.  I'm not sure I can answer why your example fails other than to say that `pyomo` is a modeling language that passes a structured math problem to a solver and the sets need to be discretely defined, not in lists of objects.  Maybe somebody else can pitch in and explain it more clearly.

In your modeling, it appears you want to construct some kind of ragged set for `x[i,j]` where the range of `j` can vary based on `i`.  You typically want to make sets for both `I` and `J` in order to support various constraint constructs.  Then you can make a subset of "valid" (i, j) tuples for whatever model component needs to be indexed by this ragged set.  You can either use this subset as the basis of iteration or use it to check membership if you are constructing things on-the-fly.

Here is an example using your list N:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

N = [1, 4, 3]

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.I  = pyo.Set(initialize=range(len(N)))
m.J  = pyo.Set(initialize=range(max(N)))
m.IJ = pyo.Set(within=m.I * m.J, initialize =
    [(i, j) for i in range(len(N)) for j in range(N[i])])

m.x = pyo.Var(m.IJ, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def _obj(model):
    return sum(m.x[t] for t in m.IJ)
m.obj = pyo.Objective(rule=_obj)

def constrain_x2(model):
    return sum(m.x[2, j] for j in m.J if (2, j) in m.IJ) >=1
m.c1 = pyo.Constraint(rule=constrain_x2)

m.pprint()
```

Yields:

```
4 Set Declarations
    I : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(0, 2)
        [0, 1, 2]
    IJ : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=8, Domain=IJ_domain, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
    IJ_domain : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=12, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual
    J : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=4, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(0, 3)
        [0, 1, 2, 3]

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=8, Index=IJ
        Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        (0, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 2) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (1, 3) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 0) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 1) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        (2, 2) :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Objective Declarations
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Sense    : Expression
        None :   True : minimize : x[0,0] + x[1,0] + x[1,1] + x[1,2] + x[1,3] + x[2,0] + x[2,1] + x[2,2]

1 Constraint Declarations
    c1 : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Lower : Body                     : Upper : Active
        None :   1.0 : x[2,0] + x[2,1] + x[2,2] :  +Inf :   True

7 Declarations: I J IJ_domain IJ x obj c1
```